# Holding password in javascript variable - security implications?

Tags: javascript, security, passwords, xss, client-side

Does holding a user's password in a javascript variable in the browser expose any specific security vulnerabilities, over and above the usual security vulnerabilities of a browser-based client?

Consider this snippet as a simple example - [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jS55M/)

```
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password"/><br/><br/>
<button type="button" id="pwdButton">Store password in window.password</button>

<script>
    function getContentsOfPasswordField() {
        return jQuery("input#password").val();
    }

    jQuery("button#pwdButton").on("click", function() {
        window.password = getContentsOfPasswordField();
        alert("'" + password + "' stored in global var window.password")
    });
</script>
```

In this example the password variable is global and persists for the lifetime of the page, just to make it as open-to-attack as possible and give the worst-case scenario. Perhaps limiting the scope/lifetime of the variable can shield it from certain classes of attacks?

The attack that comes immediately to mind is XSS, but then if the client is vulnerable to XSS in the first place, the attacker can read the password by key logging anyway (see [this](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/getting-sassy-xss-part-1-keystroke-logging)) so holding it in a variable doesn't, as far as I can see, increase vulnerability to XSS attacks.

Please note the point of the question is not really whether or not doing this is a bad practice, this is more of a fundamental question about client-side web app security.

Comment: You shouldn't "stay" on a password input page after password has been entered. 1. Possibility of other software on client machine reading password (by reading browser memory), this is a problem on the client's side and may always apply. 2. Possibility of any browser extensions reading the password. 3. Possibility of any script on the same page reading password.

Comment: But are any of these potential attacks more possible because the password is held in a variable? If malicious third-party software can access the javascript VM - can it not just keylog or read the password  when it is entered into the password input anyway?

Comment: setting it on `window` would circumvent any inbuilt security (e.g. for origin), if implemented by the client's browser. Also, if you leave your house's window open you can be robbed, but that doesn't mean you should leave your door open, too.

Comment: 'setting it on window would circumvent any inbuilt security (e.g. for origin)' - will you explain this point a little more?

Comment: That's not really the case. Only a few special-case members of `window`, such as `location`, are accessible from a remote Origin. Global variables and other custom properties written to `window` are protected by Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving the password in a variable leaves it open to people to access simply in their browser tools! 
lets say  the function called when the store password button is pressed, stores the password in a variable called password. Even if this variable is not used on the page at all after that, simply handled later on somewhere in the code, all one has to do is open up the developer tools in their browser, add in a statement like `alert(password);` , and Bam, the password literally pops up infront of them.

Admitedly, any code simple enough to let someone do that is probably unworthy of being on the web, and even less worthy of being meddled with, but I guess it's a lesson in how vunerable we really are.

Comment: true, but this is really a question about remote attacks over a network. I was assuming the user + machine are physically secure for the session!

Comment: Besides thinking about it this provides little extra opportunity to an attacker than, say, the browser storing passwords or session cookies - so nothing really out of the ordinary. The user keeping their browser physically secure is beyond the control of the web app developer.

Comment: Well, physical security is not developer's responsibility. But how about XSS kind of attack ?  I am planning to store password to automatically login to other interfacing services, and i am stuck at the security aspect of it.