# What are the security implications of storing passwords in Javascript variables?

Tags: javascript, security

I'm developing a web app which needs good security. In the present design, a number of user actions need the user to re-send their password (or else the server will have to store it in plain text, at least temporarily).

Much user interaction happens through AJAX requests. Rather than have the user re-type the password for each, I'd like to do something like this:

```
var password_plain = document .getElementById ("password") .value;

ajax ("/login.php", {password: password_plain, username: ...});

// later

ajax ("/api.php", {password: password_plain, action: ...});
```

Assume for the sake of the argument that the design is sensible in general, for example

- the server does not store or leak the plain text password,
- SSL is properly set up
- the client Javascript periodically checks that we are still logged in and sets `password_plain=null` if the session expires (and clears the DOM value)
- the server itself is secure

The threat model is that the attacker doesn't have physical access to either the client or server machine, and cannot run arbitrary code on either, but can entice the user to visit malicious other web pages in the client's browser.

Is the password safe in a javascript variable?

Comment: The only thing that really matters is that you're using HTTPS to post the login credentials, and that your server is using proper modern password hashing.

Comment: And that you have no XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: @SLaks right, XSS and CSRF protections. Basically what matters is how closely you protect server communication and guard against session exploits (XSS, CSRF). The client at the other end of the network connection is not necessarily your own code.

Comment: Related: [Holding password in javascript variable - security implications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153635/holding-password-in-javascript-variable-security-implications)

Answer (score 5):

It depends.

If you don't enclose your scopes properly, a third party script can read and modify your variables during execution (assuming it's kept for more than one event-loop tick), however, that's a bit of an edge case. As long as it's done within any sort of function or module, and you don't have an XSS vulnerability right next to it, you're golden.

There are also questions about programs who can look at memory and stuff, but that's also irrelevant because if the user has such things on their computer, your JS code is the least of their worries.

I will add however that it's not recommended that you transmit the password over and over again, you normally want to authenticate once, get some sort of one-time token (like a session token), and use that for authentication during the session. Unlike passwords, sessions are easily invalidated server-side when something goes wrong.

What *is* important is:

- HTTPS: Don't transmit passwords over the wire if they aren't encrypted. Hashing or encrypting them client-side isn't a viable solution.
- XSS or SQL Injection - Basically any kind of transition from one language to the next is dangerous. Make sure to escape rigorously right before generating statements in one language with another.
- Plain text passwords in the database - This is more of a server issue, basically, always use a strong cryptographic hash to store passwords in the database

Comment: Browser vulnerabilities, malicious plugins, and new exploits can't be guarded against. Closures, while fine at data encapsulation for the purposes of better modular design, are not adequate for securely isolating sensitive data. I would strongly reconsider storing any user credential in this way; it's simply not secure.

Comment: @Mark And yet we store session data as cookies, which is essentially a one-time password, those are normally accessible from JS, as well as MITM in the case of non-encrypted connections.

Comment: "one-time" is the key here. If that session id is stolen, the impact isn't as great as the user's primary credentials. That's why session ids are used in the first place instead of always transmitting a password.

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what you mean by "enclose your scopes properly"? I imagine you mean `(function () { var password = ... }) ()` -- or is there more to it than that?

Comment: @spraff Yeah, that's pretty much it.

Comment: @Madara'sGhost I don't understand. If you store hashed passwords in the database, then you *need* to send the plain-text password over the wire, so it can be hashed server-side.

Comment: @JuanPerez Yes? I don't understand where I say otherwise.

Comment: @Madara'sGhost Here: "HTTPS: Don't transmit passwords over the wire if they aren't encrypted. Hashing or encrypting them client-side isn't a viable solution.". But they are NOT encrypted, they are plain, because they need to be hashed server-side (as your last point suggests).

Comment: @JuanPerez By using HTTPS (or rather, TLS) you are encrypting all data in transit. No values are ever sent in plain text. A piece of malware on your router or in your ISP cannot read it, even though it was not yet hashed.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the fact that session IDs are stored in cookies and sent to the server with every request. Sound familiar? It's pretty much exactly what you're doing, but with the password instead of a session ID.

Personally I would recommend using proper sessions, but if you want a "stateless" system then what you have here should be fine, assuming as you are that everything else is "sensible" (HTTPS especially)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's absolutely not safe in a JavaScript variable. If you're storing it locally, then cross-site scripting attacks (XSS) could compromise and steal your users' credentials in plain text.

Comment: Assuming, of course, that there is an open XSS vulnerability. If the design is "sensible in general", then it will not have such vulnerabilities.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if the variable is in a closure and never exposed to the global scope, then no XSS attack can see it.

Comment: When working with security issues, it's never a good thing to assume there is no vulnerability. Even if the site is perfect, without any possibility of XSS today, that could change in a future browser update, or if the user installs a malicious plugin. It's simply not safe to store user credentials this way.

Comment: Personally I'm of the mind that "if the user installs a malicious plugin... that's not our problem".

Comment: To a certain extent that's true, but user credentials are particularly sensitive. The reality is that they're often used across sites, and usually don't have an expiry. Why expose such sensitive data needlessly when there are better solutions out there (such as session ids)? I have a feeling the answers to the original question here would be different if anyone had reason to suspect the asker worked for Amazon or a big bank. People expect their credentials to be treated better.